# Why doesn't my conversion code for roman numbers ('mcmxcix' for e.g) to real numbers work?

Tags: ruby, roman-numerals

I want to convert Roman numerals, such as "mcmxcix", to arabic integers like "1999".

My code looks like:

```
#~ I = 1 V = 5 X = 10 L = 50
#~ C = 100 D = 500 M = 1000


def roman_to_integer roman
  len = roman.length
  x = 1
  while x <= len
    arr = Array.new
    arr.push roman[x]
    x += 1
  end
  num = 0
  arr.each do |i|
    if i == 'I'
      num +=  1
    elsif i == 'V'
      num +=  5
    elsif i == 'X'
      num +=  10
    elsif i == 'L'
      num +=  50
    elsif i == 'C'
      num +=  100
    elsif i == 'D'
      num += 500
    elsif i == 'M'
      num +=  1000
    end
  end

  num
end    

puts(roman_to_integer('MCMXCIX'))
```

The output is 0, but I don't understand why?

Comment: If I had the reputation, I would have given you -1 for bad punctuation

Comment: @Programmer, if you post it in answer, I would have given you -1 for something I've haven't thought up yet...

Comment: In future, please indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have a post-increment operator. When it sees `++` it interprets that as one infix `+` followed by one prefix (unary) `+`. Since it expects an operand to follow after that, but instead finds the keyword `end`, you get a syntax error.

You need to replace `x++` with `x += 1`.

Furthermore note that `x` isn't actually in scope inside the `roman_to_integer` method (which isn't a syntax error, but nevertheless wrong).

Additionally you'll have to replace all your `if`s except the first with `elsif`s. The way you wrote it all the `if`s are nested, which means that a) you don't have enough `end`s and b) the code doesn't have the semantics you want.

Comment: hi :) 10x for your answer it was very helpful but now i have another problem the code doesn't work i edited the last code i run.. 10x agin

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parentheses so

```
puts(roman_to_integer('mcmxcix')
```

should be

```
puts roman_to_integer('mcmxcix')
```

or

```
puts(roman_to_integer('mcmxcix'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The arr keeps getting annihilated in your while loop, and it is not in the scope outside of the loop.  Move the following line above the while statement:

```
arr = Array.new
```